# Getting slope in R using Loops and conditionals

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am working on a data frame with x and y columns with values as rows.. I want to calculate the slope of x and y for every 2 rows and then using the calculated slope, record whether slope's "stability" is "high" or "low". You'll understand better after seeing the code. What is wrong with this code? When I input stability, R returns NULL.

```
slope <- (acc$y[i+1] - acc$y[i]) / (acc$x[i+1] - acc$x[i])
stability <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(acc)) {
  if (slope[i] > 0 & slope[i] < 0.8) {
    stability[i] <- "low"
  } else if (slope[i] >= 0.8 & slope[i] <= 1) {
    stability[i] <- "high"
  } else if (slope[i] > 1 & slope[i] < 1.2) {
    stability[i] <- "high"
  } else if (slope[i] >= 1.2) {
    stability[i] <- "low"
  } else if (slope[i] >= -1 & slope[i] <= -0.8) {
    stability[i] <- "high"
  } else if (slope[i] >= -0.8 & slope[i] <= 0) {
    stability[i] <- "low"
  } else if (slope[i] < -1 & slope[i] > -1.2) {
    stability[i] <- "high"
  } else 
    stability[i] <- "low"
}
```

Comment: Please make a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: When `i` equals `nrow(acc)` what is `acc$y[i+1]`... You may have to change the `for` loop to iterate only in the range`1:(nrow(acc)-1)`.

Comment: Thanks! @DiscoSuperfly

Comment: As @M.Hassan has done, it is better to do calculate the `slope` inside the loop.

Comment: Calculate all slopes at once using diff(acc$y)/diff(acc$x). Then combine your conditions with | and use the ifelse function. You don't need a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as following:

```
    #slope <- (acc$y[i+1] - acc$y[i]) / (acc$x[i+1] - acc$x[i])
     stability <- as.vector(nrow(acc))       
    n <- nrow(acc)-1
    for (i in 1:n) {
      slope <- (acc$y[i+1] - acc$y[i]) / (acc$x[i+1] - acc$x[i])         

      if (slope > 0 && slope < 0.8) {
        stability[i] <- "low"
      } else if (slope >= 0.8 && slope <= 1) {
        stability[i] <- "high"
      } else if (slope > 1 && slope < 1.2) {
        stability[i] <- "high"
      } else if (slope >= 1.2) {
        stability[i] <- "low"
      } else if (slope >= -1 && slope <= -0.8) {
        stability[i] <- "high"
      } else if (slope >= -0.8 && slope <= 0) {
        stability[i] <- "low"
      } else if (slope < -1 && slope > -1.2) {
        stability[i] <- "high"
      } else
        stability[i] <- "low"
    }
```

[Try it Online](http://rextester.com/BQKXW27702)

Comment: You need to have `()` over `nrow(acc) - 1`. As it is now, `i` starts with `0`, not 1.

Comment: I set the counter to  n <- nrow(acc)-1, thanks for hint

Comment: @ Disco Superfly , n starts with 1, bez for (i in 1:n), try the demo

Comment: That is because the code is edited now. See your previous comment where you thanked me for the hint...

Comment: @ Disco Superfly, I mean by my comment that  loop start with 1 bez it's declared in the body of "for" statement, see my old revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44981210/1  , https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44981210/2. I modified the code (nrow(acc)-1) to be enclosed between braces to avoid error, and -1 affect the end of the loop, and I'm still thank you:)